# Can i use a wix installer to just run a couple of custom commands

Tags: powershell, wix, installation

I am working on a project where we need to repeat certain steps with powershell to deploy stuff. i would like to create a process/install guidance (steps supported with UI) with WIX but after the msi has finished i have an entry in programs and features. I just need it to execute  the powershell and the end without registering in windows. i might be using the wrong tooling or whatever, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not recommended unless you want to track the deployment of these scripts on different systems by checking the entries in ARP (Add/Remove Programs), and even then it clogs up the Add/Remove view of your computers. Most system administrators hate this approach, it is better to just write to your own registry key and read it back from every machine.

What are the scripts doing? Are you actually installing files.

Comment: the scripts are uploading files to a server and checking them in on the portal. the installer is there mainly to execute these scripts and should leave no trail on the pc that executed it (including arp and file system)

Comment: I wouldn't use MSI for this. If I were you I would post the same question on http://serverfault.com/ where system administrators respond. They probably have lots of alternative ways you could do this.